# Can range lock in SQL be acquired in share mode

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading, transactions

I have a query such as

```
Select count(*) from table log where num = ?;
```

If I set the isolation level to serializable, then the range lock will be acquired for the where clause.

My question is: Can other transaction also acquire the **range lock in share mode** to read the count as the above OR the **range lock is exclusive** and all other transactions have to wait until the current transaction commits before executing the above read query.

***Background***: I am trying to implement a view counter for heavy traffic website. To reduce IO to the database, I create a log table so that every time there is a view, I only write a new row in the log table. Once a while, I (randomly) decide if I want to clear the log table and add the number of rows in the log table into a column of a view count table. This means I have to be careful with interleaving transaction.

Comment: As an aside, why do you think inserting a row per view reduces I/O as opposed to the more obvious approach of doing an `UPDATE` per row? An `INSERT` is usually a hotspot at the end of the table, while an `UPDATE` at worst increases contention on locking (but less on I/O), assuming there's an index and you're updating only one row. Make sure to test both approaches. Also, if you have SQL Server 2016 Enterprise, strongly consider in-memory OLTP for this, because this is the sort of thing it was made for.

Comment: @JeroenMostert We try `UPDATE` before, it does not scale. MySQL hangs with too many read and write

Comment: Is your question about MySQL or about SQL Server? If the former, it's not correctly tagged (and I'll have to delete my answer since I can't make any statements about MySQL).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think it applies to all SQL servers since Youtube for example also does not have exact view count. If you check on a popular video, after you view it the view count is not updated right away. They also batch the view count update it looks like.

Comment: The general issue applies to all servers, but the strategies used by servers to prevent this issue are certainly *not* all the same. Comparable, but not the same. I cannot tell you if MySQL uses intent locks just like SQL Server does, for example (which is how SQL Server prevents deadlocks). Nor is it a requirement that servers lock -- snapshot isolation does not, but MySQL doesn't have snapshot isolation. For all I know MySQL makes all `SELECT` statements take table locks under `SERIALIZABLE`! I highly doubt it does, but I don't know.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for the insight nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

The statements below are relevant only to SQL Server and were made before the OP made clear this was really about MySQL, about which I know nothing. I'm leaving it here since it (and the resulting discussion) might be of some use nevertheless, but it is not a complete, relevant answer to the question.

---

`SELECT` statements only ever acquire shared locks, on all isolation levels (unless overridden with a table hint). And shared locks are always compatible with each other (see [Lock Compatibility](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms186396)), so there's no problem if other transactions want to acquire shared (range) locks as well. So yes, you can have any number of queries performing `SELECT COUNT(*)` in parallel and they will never block each other.

This doesn't mean other transactions don't have to wait. In particular, a `DELETE` query must eventually acquire an exclusive lock, and it will have to wait if the `SELECT` is holding a shared lock. Normally this is not an issue since the engine releases locks as soon as possible. When it does become an issue, you'll want to look at solutions like [snapshot isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/tcbchxcb), which uses optimistic concurrency and conflict detection rather than locking. Under that model, a `SELECT` will never block any other query (save those that want table locks). Of course, this isn't free; the row versioning is uses takes up disk space and I/O.

Comment: Can you have a reference to back up "`SELECT` statements only ever acquire shared locks". If range lock can be acquired in share mode, there is a danger of deadlock. Imagine a scenario where transaction 1 (T1) and T2 acquire shared range lock, then T1 goes ahead to acquire an exclusive write lock (on a row), then waits to acquire exclusive range lock. T2 waits to acquire exclusive write lock (on the row) while holding the range lock in share mode preventing T1 from going a head.

Comment: In SQL Server, the locking scenario you described is not possible. SQL Server has intent-exclusive locks to prevent exactly this scenario from happening -- a data modification statement will first take an intent-exclusive lock that does not block readers but does block updaters, then upgrade this to an exclusive lock when the data modification happens (with range locks always taking place before row locks).

Comment: But T1 gets blocked when it tries to acquire exclusive range lock (ie upgrading the lock from share to exclusive). Meanwhile, T2 tries to acquire an exclusive lock on a row which is held by T1. This is deadlock. This deadlock will not happen, if range lock is acquirable in exclusive mode only. In that case, T1 gets the exclusive range lock with `SELECT` statement, T2 can never acquire range lock. T1 finishes and T2 can continue.

Comment: My head hurts. I know a deadlock will not happen (assuming we have only one index on the table), I also know `SELECT` will only acquire shared locks (`SELECT` statements do *not* block each other, ever, and this is trivial to demonstrate), but I cannot immediately rattle off the sequence of locks that will happen in this case. SQL Server has no less than 21 different types of locks, of which 9 range locks. Combined with the fact that I have no idea how MySQL behaves, it means I'm going to abandon this answer.